# Is it possible to use generic passives in Altium and update the BOM with part numbers at the end?

Tags: pcb-design, schematics, altium

I have just started using Altium and am unsure of the best way to deal with generic 'jelly bean' components such as passives, discrete and parts such as 0.1" headers etc.

I know I have to make my question specific so here is how I would like to do it but need help on how to achieve it:

When starting a new design I would like to add resistors and caps etc without having to research specific part numbers beforehand, for example, I would like to add a 0805 resistor, then set its properties such as value, voltage rating, tolerance and power rating. I can then carry on with the design and layout.

Then when I generate my BOM I can either research the part number that suits the properties or let my assembler place their parts that also match. Also, by doing this I can have an integrated library with just resistor footprints and one symbol.

How do I do this in Altium?

Answer (score 1):

There is no inherent problem with the approach you describe. Use generic components for your first schematics version, use any of the fields available (e.g. description or value) to add your needed details in human readable form.

Later you can easily replace the components with specific ones by editing the "Design Item ID" (don't delete and place new, this will destroy identifiers). If the generic and specific component have the same symbol and footprint, you don't have to make any changes in the schematics nor the layout. All you need to do is regenerate the BOM.

You could also make a new symbol for each component immediately - it's not necessary to have all the details available in the library from the beginning. It's simple to add details like part numbers later on when you finalize your design. You can easily update your schematics with the latest version of the components from the library ("Update from Library"). This is the way I usually do it.

Over time you'll have a library with the specific components you need the most and can use them right away, which will save you additional time.